# How to play a video(avi) on xna4.0?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

Im new to xna. I'm creating a platform game for windows pc only and somehow needs to play an avi file
how can I do this on xna 4.0 or c# 2010?
anyone can help? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this creating video player instance

```
Video video;
VideoPlayer player;
Texture2D videoTexture;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    video = Content.Load<Video>("video");
    player = new VideoPlayer();
}
```

here is the source of article with more examples
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904199.aspx

here are couple more dll

http://scurvymedia.codeplex.com/

http://xnadsplayer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you but what will I do in the update,draw? position? and the msdn sample didnt work

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://xna-uk.net/media/p/1973.aspx) has some working code that you can download with xna media players.  The project actually puts video on a 3d object (perhaps a little overkill for what you are trying to do), but I can imagine you could study the code that does the video playback to see how it works.  There is a VideoPlayer class inside the project; maybe you can give that a look.